# How to undo sudo add-apt-repository?

Tags: linux, debian, apt, package-management, lubuntu

I ran

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/indicators
```

to install `my-weather-indicator` but it requires GTK3 and I don't want to proceed further.

So I'd like to undo that command. I've checked my `/etc/apt/source.list` but I didn't find any line related to it.

What should I do now?

Comment: If somebody is looking for how to do that in (open)SUSE/SLES, you can consider [this zypper guide](https://treehozz.com/how-do-i-remove-zypper-repository): `zypper removerepo xyz`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[`add-apt-repository`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/add-apt-repository.1.html) creates a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for ppa repositories. Besides deleting the appropriate file you also should delete the added gpg key:

1. get the keyid  from `apt-key list`
2. delete it via `apt-key del $ID`

Comment: Item 1 returns `pub 1024R/36FD5529 2010-12-14 uid Launchpad PPA for noobslab`. What is its `$ID`?

Comment: @Sigur `36FD5529` is the id, `1024` is the keylength and the rest is the uid

Comment: It works with `del` instead of `delete`.

Comment: This above answer is non-working in Debian (which is far superior to Ubuntu).  In Debian, you need to edit /etc/apt/sources.list with privileges.  `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and then just delete the entries and press ^x to exit and y to save changes.

Answer (score 90):

From Ubuntu's manual pages (`man add-apt-repository`):

> `-r`, `--remove` Remove the specified repository

So...

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:noobslab/indicators
```

This removes it from the repo list in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/.

**Depending on what you are doing, BEFORE you run the above command -**
If an installed package from that repo is newer than the same package in a standard repo, then manually downgrade with [ppa-purge](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa):

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:noobslab/indicators
```

For Debian, just delete the .list file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: Where can I check if it worked? Are there some entries in `source.list`?

Comment: @Sigur Yes! The .list files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/.

Comment: Your first suggestion returns *You are about to add the following PPA to your system:*. The second one returns *sudo: ppa-purge: command not found*. I still have `.list` in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Comment: Strangely, I'm on 14.04 and there is no -r nor --remove option for me.

Comment: The command:    sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:noobslab/indicators    works perfectly.     It's also convenient, as I can recall the previous command of adding the repository just add the -r switch after the command, before the repository name.

Comment: Why isn't this the accepted answer...

Comment: strange, on 18.04 I had to `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Comment: also, i don't know if the ppa-purge succeeded or not because it says nothing about removing anything, but complains about an unrelated ppa not having a release file, after which it says `Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to undo `add-apt-repository`, having used a format like e.g.

```
sudo add-apt-repository \
   "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
   $(lsb_release -cs) \
   stable"
```

Use the output displayed by the following command to find the repository you want to delete

```
grep ^ /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Example output:

`/etc/apt/sources.list:#deb cdrom:[Linux Mint 17.3 _Rosa_ - Release amd64 20151128]/ trusty contrib main non-free
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu trusty stable
...`

In this example `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list` would have the repository to undo/remove. Edit the file and remove its line.

Comment: Why use `grep ^` instead `cat`?