# http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish Release 404 Not Found

Tags: linux, debian

Hi I Have a linux server (debian 10 buster)

after typing the command: `sudo apt-get update` for  updating

there was en error shown :

```
Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease                                                                                         
Get:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg InRelease [110 kB]                                                                                                           
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                                                              
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease [23.9 kB]                                                                                
Hit:7 https://packages.sury.org/php buster InRelease                                       
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 1200:89c:6950:8000::17 80]
Get:9 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt buster-pgdg/main amd64 Packages [246 kB]
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4E..
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4E.....
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu impish InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php7.list:1
```

How i could solve that please?

Comment: (1) you should not follow Ubuntu-specific tutorials on your Debian server. (2) If you add third-party software sources, you should know what you're doing. Adding these repositories **may** work, but more likely they will introduce a lot of issues. `impish` is an Ubuntu release (21.10) and "No Release file" means, this version is not supported by the maintainer of the repository.

Comment: Debian : gearman packages are available by default https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=gearman

Comment: cross posted https://superuser.com/questions/1698698/http-ppa-launchpad-net-ondrej-pkg-gearman-ubuntu-impish-release-404-not-found

Answer (score 2):

The repository you are pointing to does not support `impish`.  The latest version of Ubuntu supported seems to be `focal`.  It's not uncommon for PPAs to become unmaintained after a while.  That may be what happened here.

As you are using Debian `buster` as your primary source, you'll only want to add sources that work with Debian `buster`.  Adding Ubuntu archives to a debian machine is not supported.

I took a quick look in the [Debian archive](https://packages.debian.org/buster/php-gearman) and package `php-gearman` is available in the Debian archive.  So, I suggest to simply delete the PPA and `sudo apt install php-gearman`. This will install a version of `php-gearman` which is sure to work with the rest of your system.

It's not uncommon to see tutorials which suggest a PPA.  That's usually written by a dev who suggests you have the latest version of the software instead of the stable version which has been reviewed by the distro.  But it's only the stable version which is sure to work on your system.  [Don't suffer from shiny new stuff syndrome](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_suffer_from_Shiny_New_Stuff_Syndrome).

Comment: Thanks but How i can delete the PPA I mean with witch command?

Comment: "*Don't suffer from shiny new stuff syndrome.*" - Correct! And if you still do, do not use Debian (or at least run it in e.g. `docker` environment)

Comment: Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60595/how-to-undo-sudo-add-apt-repository) how to remove repositories.

Comment: I have did :sudo add-apt-repository --remove http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu
sudo add-apt-repository --remove http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/pkg-gearman and /ubuntu then : sudo apt install php-gearman ,But nothing work always same error when i do updating via sudo apt-get update

Comment: Take a look at `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`.  In there you will find lines that looks like `deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/...`.  Delete those lines, then run `sudo apt update`.